# there must be some difference between python lambda and regular function?

Tags: python, lambda

I tried 2 snippets to figure out the difference between python lambda and regular function.

this one get what is expected.

```
b = range(6)
def greater_than2(b):
    if b > 2:
        return b

print(list(filter(lambda x: x > 2, b)))
print(list(filter(greater_than2, b)))
```

both print give [3, 4, 5].

but something goes with this one

```
b = range(6)

def less_than2(b):
    if b < 2:
        return b

print(list(filter(lambda x: x < 2, b)))
print(list(filter(less_than2, b)))
```

i got following output

```
[0, 1]
[1]
```

so, what the difference between the lambda and less_than2 function?

Comment: Your functions should be returning true or false, not `b`. When `b` is zero, `less_than2(b)` returns `0`, which is a falsey value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your functions are not comparable, `greater_than2` needs to return a Boolean:

```
def greater_than2(b):
    return b > 2
```

The function defined above will return `True` when `b > 2`, or `False` when `b <= 2`.

Your regular functions return `b`. Let's consider what happens with your second example, where you see a discrepancy:

`b = 0`: `less_than2` returns `0`
`b = 1`: `less_than2` returns `1`
`b = 2`: `less_than2` returns `None`
...
`b = 5`: `less_than2` returns `None`

Notice if your `if` condition is not satisfied, a `return` statement is never met and therefore your function will return `None`. The only "Truthy" value of these return values is `1` as `bool(0)` and `bool(None)` evaluate to `False`.